# WCF: Dispose() vs IContextChannel.Closed

Tags: c#, wcf, idisposable

I have implemented a WCF service, per-session, concurrencymode = multiple, usesynccontext = false, object, and it implements IDisposable, and in its constructor, gets a pointer (C#) to IContextChannel, and signs up for events Closing and Closed.

When a client has connected to my service and is done with it, my service always gets the Closing event first, but then sometimes it's followed up by a call to Dispose() THEN the event Closed comes in, and sometimes it gets the Closed event first, then a call to Dispose(). I want to know (a) why, and (b) how to work around it so I know when to throw stuff out.

My C# service uses stuff down in unmanaged code. It also shuts down asynchronously. When I get the closing event, I start shutting things down. In either Dispose() or Closed, I need to wait for those unmanaged things to go away (because another call to the service will necessarily allocate and use those resources). So, I *have* to wait.

My thoughts are that once Dispose() is called on my service, the event I've set up to receive Closed may face a race condition that contends with the GC cleaning up my object. Maybe I don't understand Dispose() very well. I *thought* I couldn't look at the contents of the C# object after Dispose() was called. But if the Closed event comes in after Dispose(), I need to look at the contents of the C# object and release them. Maybe Dispose() just gives me a chance to throw things out, and my object is still valid until the objects destructor (Finalizer!) is called? And I thus don't need to worry?

Comment: I'm not asking how to know when to throw things out. I'm asking "what is the correct order that Closed Event vs Dispose() will get called and where should my cleanup be done, Dispose() or Closed" ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear without code, for a workaround you can use a flag and set this flag on closed event and check for value in Dispose() if meet do clean up, you also can call dispose() explicity from Closed() event handler after setting flag value,

you can define your flag as a bool "IsClosedEventHandled=true/false"